# Using PSGI, is it possible to change how uploaded files are named?

Tags: perl, plack, psgi

I have a small PSGI app which takes an upload from a form and passes it off to another script for processing:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Plack::Request;
use HTTPStatusCode;

my $app = sub {
    my $req = Plack::Request->new(shift);

    my $content;
    if (keys %{$req->uploads}) {
        $content = do_something_with_upload($req);
    } else {
        $content = display_form();
    }

    return [
        HTTPStatusCode->SUCCESS,
        [ 'Content-type', 'text/html' ],
        [ $content ],
    ];
};
```

The file gets uploaded successfully as something like `/tmp/Fw8n6j0ICn.txt`. The problem is, the processing relies on the file being named as it was when uploaded.

Is it possible to change how files are uploaded so they go to `/tmp/Fw8n6j0ICn/original_name.txt` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can retrieve the original filename via `filename` method of `$request` object, so you can basically copy the `$request->path` to whatever you desire and process that file.